# Windows debugging “Error: spawn ENOENT” on node.js

Tags: node.js, windows, pm2, spawn, enoent

spawn pm2 process on windows can only launch a .bat or .exe. Need to enable {shell: true} for it to actually work.

While debugging spawn on windows the ridiculous error of "spawn pm2 ENOENT" became apparent. After digging around and finding absolutely no real solutions on the deity StackOverflow, I dug around on a bunch of GitHub issues finally finding an adequate solution for Windows spawn.

True solution found https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/2318

### @DrPizza solution

@OrangeDog Well you can't really write a portable batch file anyway.

@DrPizza suggested today that we could add a { shell: true } option to spawn. I kind of like the idea. It allows using spawn for the same purpose as exec without buffering all the output. We also currently have the weird distinction between exec and execFile; we could just make those the same function but with a different default for the shell option. @ry, @bnoordhuis, what do you guys think?

### For me the ultimate solution is as follows

let env = env === 'production' ? 'prod' : 'sand'; // context for env variable

let deploy = spawn('pm2', ['deploy', env, 'update', '&&', 'pm2', 'deploy', env, 'exec', '"sudo pm2 reload "'], {shell: true});